# How To Enable a User in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I Made Bad Mistake And Disable All Users In SQL
Is There Any Way With cmd Or RegEdit To Enable One User?

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995421/enable-user-in-sql-server

Comment: No I Cant Connect to SQL Server

Comment: Database  on remote server or local?

Comment: Even the admin accounts? SQL Server Agent accounts? How did you do that? How could a command disable the account that executed it without throwing/ You can use the [dedicated admin connection](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-dedicated-admin-connection-dac-how-to-enable-connect-and-use/) to connect when no other connection can, but even that needs authentication